# New battery going dead

Tags: battery-drain

Bought a new battery for my truck it's a 1993 Chevy 3500. The battery tested good after two weeks it was dead. Every time I get into drive it I have to jump the battery. took it to a mechanic alternator is fine nothing is draining the battery could a new battery have something wrong with it and test good

Comment: Probably not a bad battery, something is draining it.

Comment: New batteries can fail, but having dealt with hundreds that failure rate is **very** low. Test all the items again and check for poor connections.